# How to use the go commands in Netlogo's Behavior Space

Tags: netlogo

I have a Netlogo model that I can use by setting a slider and then pressing the buttons in my interface once each in the following order: setup, go, SetSeed, Share. This all works fine.

I'd like to use Behavior Space to run this 100 times with various values of the slider.

I can get it to work with just setup and go but when I try to include SetSeed and Share the program hangs.

I have put `setup` in the 'Setup Commands:' box and `go` in the 'Go Commands:' boxes and that bit works fine.

To then add in SetSeed and Share I have tried adding the following to 'Go Commands:' in the following format:

go

SetSeed

Share

When I try `SetSeed` or `Share` on their own without `go` (just to see what happens) it also hangs (the steps just keep going up and up). Does anyone know what might cause this? I thought Go Commands essentially just had the computer press those buttons once rather then having a user do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify how long you want the run to last, either by entering a number of steps in the experiment setup (in your case, `1`), or by specifying a stop condition, for example, you might have the run stop when `not any? turtles` becomes true.  This is documented at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#how

Comment: Thank you for this. I added the stop command to the end of the Share procedure and it now runs, terminates and produces the right number of outputs, but it still doesn't behave as if someone is pressing the Share button once. It's as if Share gets pressed many times over.

Comment: That's correct. That's the behavior we designed and I think it's the behavior we documented, too. Is there something in the user interface or the documentation that led you to expect something different? Note that you won't need to use `stop` if you just specify in your experiment setup that you want the experiment to only last for one step.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the comment above, the following hack seemed to work. I rewrote the go procedure making it a run once procedure:

```
to go
  getGo ;This procedure does the job that the go command originally did
  SetSeed
  Share
  stop
end
```

In the go commands I now just have 'go'.